# Creating copy of a file at one position up in the same folder/directory location

Tags: c#, .net, ios-ui-automation

I have a Path;

```
\\\\username-txd\location\Configuration\MediaManagerConfig\Web.config
```

I want to create a copy of file at one position up in the same folder i.e.

```
\\\\username-txd\location\Configuration\Web.config
```

Can anyone help me with the code since I am new to C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DirectoryInfo.Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx) returns this `MediaManagerConfig` and you can do little bit string manupalition like;

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\\\username-txd\location\Configuration\MediaManagerConfig\Web.config");
Console.WriteLine(di.FullName.Replace(di.Parent.Name + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, ""));
```

Result will be;

```
\\username-txd\location\Configuration\Web.config
```

If you want 4 back slash based on your result, your can replace with `\\` to `\\\\` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `File.Copy` to copy the file.
To get your destination file name, you can do

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)), Path.GetFileName(path));
```

with 'path' the full path with the file name.
You need to import `System.IO`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use seomthing like the power of the `DirectoryInfo` class. It knows the relationship on the filesystem and provides e.g. the `.Parent` property:

```
string originalFilename = "\\\\username-txd\\location\\Configuration\\MediaManagerConfig\\Web.config";
string originalPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(originalFilename);
string newPath = Path.Combine(new DirectoryInfo(originalPath).Parent.FullName, Path.GetFileName(originalFilename));
```